# How to get closest value for each decades in c#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, listbox

I am getting data by using timer and adding them to in a listbox or datagridview. I need to get values for each decades such as;`10,20,30,40,50..`

But not always data comes as much as in order that I want. There is a example data that comes;
`10.15
 14.45
 19.65
 22.18
 27.89
 30.15
 31.15
 37.46
 42.01
 ...`

According to data above I want to list this data in my code;

`10.15 as 10
 19.65 as 20
 30.15 as 30
 42.01 as 40
  ...`

As you see I don't want to miss any decade. 
In my code `label1.text represents velocity`, `label2.Text represents time` and `watch is a stopwatch` Firstly I am collecting data to lisboxes then take them to datagirview.Here is my code;

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    watch.Start();
    var time = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    if (Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(label1.Text)) % 10 == 0)
    {
        listBoxTime.Items.Add(label2.Text);
        listBoxVelocity.Items.Add(label1.Text);
        p = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        for (int i = 1; i < listBoxTime.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[p].Cells[0].Value = listBoxVelocity.Items[i].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[p].Cells[1].Value = listBoxTime.Items[i].ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

As I said before, What should I do to get closest data for each decade without missing any decade.

Comment: I expect 10.5, since it is more closer to 10 than 11.5.

Comment: What do you expect 15 to round to? What about 25?

Comment: Would it occur that there's a situation that has a decade missing?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running? What version of .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: I Use visual studio 2013 and .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

You could just divide the numbers by ten, then round them, followed by multiply by ten. Check the difference between the two and compare it to previous ones.

**Update**: *(the previous answer removed)*
Now just getting the lowest. Probably not most elegant/generic way, but it should work.
**Update2**:
Replaced C#6 code

```
class Numbers {
    public int Rounded { get; set; }
    public double Number { get; set; }
    public double Difference
    {
        get { return Math.Abs(Rounded - Number); }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = new [] {10.15, 14.45, 19.65, 22.18, 27.89, 30.15, 31.15, 37.46, 42.01};
        var decades = new List<Numbers>();

        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            var rounded = (int)Math.Round(number / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10;
            var found = decades.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Rounded == rounded);

            if (found == null)
                decades.Add(new Numbers { Rounded = rounded, Number = number });
            else if (found.Difference > Math.Abs(rounded - number))
                found.Number = number;
        }

        foreach (var number in decades)
            Console.WriteLine($"{number.Number} as {number.Rounded}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
10.15 as 10
19.65 as 20
30.15 as 30
42.01 as 40
```

I'm not sure if you want to hold on to numbers that didn't make the cut, but that shouldn't be too hard to add.

**Change**

```
public double Difference => MathAbs(Rounded - Number);
```

**C#6 Alternative-1**

```
public double Difference() {
    return Math.Abs(Rounded - Number);
}
```

**C#6 Alternative-2**

```
public double Difference { 
    {
        get { return Math.Abs(Rounded - Number); }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that he's expecting a new array that only contains the values closest to a decade. In his example it would give `[10.15, 19.65, 30.15,  42.01]`

Comment: @mjwills thanks for pointing out the midpoint rounding. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @nGAGE thanks for your reply but in his solution if there is a numbers as 11,12,13,14 , it takes all of them as 10. But I want to get only the closest one so which is 11 for this.

Comment: @Quanthema Sorry, I guess I misunderstood. Hope that update2 helps.

Comment: @nGAGE Thanks you so much for your repsonse but In class Numbers part ` public double Difference => Math.Abs(Rounded - Number);` gives an error.

Comment: @Quanthema Ok, sorry. the syntax is a c# 6 feature. Let me add an example of what the code means/does and should resolve it for you.

Comment: @Quanthema There is an edge-case I can think of that might break the code, but I'm not sure if it will apply. If the source number is 100 or greater, the division & multiplication by 10 part wouldn't work anymore. I am assuming that you're only getting numbers from .01~99.99 though. Is that an accurate assumption?

Comment: Thanks for point this out @mjwills Spotted a difference with my own code and eventually unnecessary fall-through elseif. Updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution shows one possible approach. To use this, be sure to add [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) to your project.

*The code basically rounds to the nearest decade, then chooses the entry which is **closest** (i.e. smallest difference) as the example.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MoreLinq;

class Program
{
    private static IEnumerable<DecadeAndClosest> GroupByDecade(double[] input)
    {
        var rounded = input.Select(z => new
        {
            original = z,
            rounded = Math.Round(z / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10
        });
        var roundedWithDifference =
            rounded.Select(z => new { z.original, z.rounded, difference = Math.Abs(z.original - z.rounded) });
        var finalResults = roundedWithDifference.GroupBy(z => z.rounded)
            .Select(z => new DecadeAndClosest() { Decade = z.Key, Example = z.MinBy(Y => Y.difference).original });
        return finalResults;
    }

    public class DecadeAndClosest
    {
        public double Decade { get; set; }
        public double Example { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = new[]
        {
            10.15,
            14.45,
            19.65,
            22.18,
            27.89,
            30.15,
            31.15,
            37.46,
            42.01
        };

        var finalResults = GroupByDecade(input);

        foreach (var indiv in finalResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", indiv.Decade, indiv.Example));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it will work anywhere. I included the complete console app code for you to test it. You can copy and paste `GroupByDecade` and `DecadeAndClosest` into any type of project (as long as it has the Nuget package that I mentioned).

Comment: Thanks you so much for your response but code gives an error at this part `Example = z.MinBy(Y => Y.difference).original`. Also my code works with timer tick and I can't make your code imposed to work with timer interval.

Comment: Did you add the Nuget package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/

Comment: `I can't make your code imposed to work with timer interval` What part of it could you not get working with a timer?

Comment: I added Nuget package. For example my label1 .Text changes according to timer. I added your  `var input= new[] {Convert.to(Double.Label1.Text)}` into timer tick part. but it doesn't work . I tried to change your variable `original=Convert.toDouble(label1.Text)` but it gives an error. As a brief Which variables in your code refers my label1.Text. Think that you are in the car and getting faster data comes from gps and you show you velocity in label1 and you want to measure time velocity relations in every decades. to do it I should work with timer.